# How to save text/data in cocoa/xcode to a file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, file-io

i'm sorry for the obvious question, but is there something i should be careful about when writing data to a file, because my program can read the data it just wrote, while the program is running, but the moment i stop it, the files become empty

tried using NSFileHandle, in order to write data with it, and close the file later, didn't help... currently, i'm using:

```
NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:newArray];
[encodedObject writeToFile:string atomically:YES];
```

and no matter what i do, i can't get the simplest NSString to stay in the file permanently

what do i do?

Thanks @LetzFlow, but it didn't solve it just yet.

Now, i'm using:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.rtf",fileName];    
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:string];

//NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:file];
NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:newArray];

[encodedObject writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
//[fileHandle writeData:encodedObject];
//[fileHandle closeFile];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil]);
```

to serialize an array of objects, and it the NSLog shows a valid array. Yet, when I look at the file later, or try to unserialize the array (like this):

```
NSString *stringX = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.rtf",fileName];
NSData *encodedObjectX = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:stringX];
NSArray *newArrayX = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObjectX];
TurnigButton *button = [[newArrayX objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:5];
NSLog(@"%d", button.idNum);
```

it just prints (null). (when they execute one after the other in a single run, it unserializes just fine)

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Try this: 1. Run from the simulator, 2. stop, 3. check for the existing of the saved file on your MAC's hd.

Comment: Tried, doesn't work... The files remain empty.

Answer (score 0):

The question is WHERE do you write your file? Because you are not allowed to write files all over the system in iOS.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

The documents directory is usually a place were you can write files, so you might want to give that a try.